# Proof verification: given a field $k$, any finite group can be represented as $\rm Gal(E/F)$ where $k\subset F\subset E$ and $E/F$ is Galois.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $G$ be an arbitrary finite group. It seems to me that one can construct  fields $F$ and $E$ such that $k\subset F\subset E$ and $\rm Gal$$(E/F)$ is isomorphic to $G$ as follows:

By Cayley's theorem, $G$ can be embedded into a symmetric group $S_n$ for some integer $n$. Let $E$ be the quotient field of polynomial ring $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ where $X_1, ...,X_n$ are $n$ independent variables. Then there is a natural isomorphism between $S_n$ and the subgroup $H$ of $\rm Gal$$(E/k)$ such that any $\sigma\in H$ permutes the set $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$. Let $G_0$ denote the subgroup of $H$ isomorphic to $G$, and denote $E^{G_0}$ by $F$. Since $G_0$ is finite, by Artin's throrem we know $E$ is Galois over $F$ and $G_0=$$\rm Gal$$(E/F)$.

It seems that there are something not correct in this proof but I cannot tell which part is wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: What if k is the complex field?

Comment: There is a way to make this work, but not with $E/k$ finite, and not as written. In your argument, what does $\mathrm{Gal}(E/k)$ actually mean? $E$ is not an algebraic extension of $k$. You certainly can't blindly apply the fundamental theorem of Galois theory to it. Your argument can be fixed by observing that $E':=E^{S_n}$ is just the field generated over $k$ by all the symmetric polynomials in $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, and that $E/E'$ is finite with Galois group $S_n$ (this requires proof). Then the rest of your argument makes sense. But $E'$ is not even an algebraic extension of $k$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you. In my proof, $\rm Gal$$(E/k)$ is the subgroup of $\rm Aut$$(E)$ whose restriction on $k$ happens to be the identity map. It could be an out-of-time traditon that this notation has no such meaning as  '$E/k$ is algebraic' in the 20th century literature, c.f. Page 275,  *Algebra: A Graduate Course* by I.Martin Isaacs (who emphasizes that $E/k$ is an arbitrary field extension), and Page 200 of *Advanced Modern Algebra* by Joseph J.Rotman.

Comment: @Mathmo123  And the following arguments need not to be based on the fundamental theorem. It depends on another theorem, asserting that for **any** field $E$ and arbitrary **finite** subgroup $G$ of $\rm Aut$$(E)$, $E$ is finite Galois over $F=E^{G}$ and $\rm Gal$$(E/F)=G$. I am confirmed that this result does not dependent on $E/F$,  because both Artin and Isaacs have extract part of their proof as a lemma where they **prove** $E$ is algebraic over $F=E^{G}$. (c.f. Page 553-555 in Artin's *Algebra*,  or Page 282 and 285, Lemma 18.14 and Theorem 18.20 in Isaacs' *Algebra: A Graduate Course*)

Comment: @zyy that all sounds reasonable - it's just not usually taught in a first course in Galois theory. But, in that case, I think your proof is fine.